# Could SSL (DV) certificates be used to identify a network of sites?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to get a good grasp on what information you could actually extract from a SSL-certificate. I'm running a network of sites hosted on the same VPS, with multiple domains that all point to unique IPs - could creating certificates using Certbot for these sites somehow reveal their relationship?

Answer (score 0):

It depends...

If you run `cerbot` separately for each site, they'll have their own certificates, which are all unique and unrelated.

However, if you run `certbot` once to enrol a single certificate with Subject Alternative Name entries listing all of your sites, then visiting any site will result in you being presented with the same server certificate.  Just reading the Subject Alternative Name will list all the hostnames within the network of sites.